# How to send an access_token and id_token to an api using System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, jwt

how can you send both the access_token and id_token to your api using System.Net.Http? when i was testing my api with postman it seemed to send both tokens and returned the individual user information I needed (a list of products the user is selling). I am unsure how I can do this in my Xamarin app and have being stuck on this for quite some time. I am able to send the access_token as shown below but anything I have tried when sending both tokens has returned a 404 not found. (unauthorized is corrected to a 401 so the access_token is still working)

```
        public async Task<string> GetResponseJsonString(string url)
        {
            string responseJsonString = null;
            var access_token = CrossSecureStorage.Current.GetValue("access_token");           
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                responseJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            return responseJsonString;
        }
```

***Note:*** I am aware the id_token should contain the user information and it should be decoded rather than sending requests for user information. I looked at this and have been unable to find a library that works in a xamarin PCL. I looked at JosePCL.Jwt but was unable to get it to work. I figure since any time I need user information it is returning information from my database that it made sense to send both tokens with the request and let my api get the user information.

Answer (score 0):

This is entirely dependent on the API you're calling. I've never seen an API that needs something more than the access_token it's provided back to you. It's possible you have the nomenclature incorrect here.

Do you mean "access key & secret"? Or are you certain you have an access_token?

In the former case, normally API's will expect things as followed:

- Append the key & secret together separated by a ":"
- Base64 Encode
- Set the `Authorization Bearer|Basic` header with the result

It's also worth asking if you've tried passing in the `id_token` as the `Authorization` header?

It's also also worth asking if you can provide us with a screen capture of the successful response from postman (make sure you obfuscate the sensitive data).

It's also also also worth pointing out an optimization tweak for your code. Since you're using `async`, it seems you probably are somewhat concerned about performance. Have a look at [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) article, discussing the disposability of HttpClient. As a better alternative, use `HttpRequestMessage` as follows:

```
public async Task<string> GetResponseJsonString(string url)
{
    string responseJsonString = null;

    var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/your/api/url");             
    req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);

    using (var resp = await client.SendAsync(req))
    using (var s = await resp.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
    {
        if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            responseJsonString = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            string errorMessage = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
            int statusCode = (int)resp.StatusCode;

            //log your error
        }
    }    

    return responseJsonString;
}
```

Where `client` is a reference to a statically shared instance of `HttpClient`. My preferred way to do all this, is to wrap my API calls, usually one-file-per-service. I inject this service as a singleton, which will broker it's own static instance of `HttpClient`. This setup is even more straightforward if you're using .NET Core.